# Visibility of the Magento Partial Index process

Tags: php, mysql, magento, indexing, cron

Magento Enterprise 1.13+ uses a 'partial index' process which runs in the background as part of the Magento cron job. I'm currently struggling to get any visibility into what this process is doing.

I understand the partial indexer works by keeping track of entities to re-index via 'changelog' tables in the database (`catalog_category_flat_cl`, `catalog_category_product_cat_cl`, etc.), then reindexes these specific items when cron runs.

The Magento cron is currently running on my server (the same cron process has been running for around 3 hours). The `cron_schedule` table indicates that `enterprise_refresh_index` is in progress and started at the same time as the aforementioned cron process kicked off.

However, when I count the rows in the changelog tables, the values are always the same; the number of rows in those tables isn't decreasing (which I'd expect if the partial indexer was processing them?). The n98-magerun tool lists the indexes, but none of them are currently being processed:

```
$ n98-magerun.phar index:list
+------------------------------+-----------------+------+
| code                         | status          | time |
+------------------------------+-----------------+------+
| catalog_product_attribute    | require_reindex | 28m  |
| catalog_product_price        | pending         | 0    |
| catalog_url                  | pending         | 0    |
| catalog_product_flat         | pending         | 0    |
| catalog_category_flat        | pending         | 0    |
| catalog_category_product     | pending         | 0    |
| catalogsearch_fulltext       | pending         | 0    |
| cataloginventory_stock       | pending         | 0    |
| tag_summary                  | require_reindex | 1s   |
| url_redirect                 | pending         | 0    |
| catalog_url_category         | pending         | 0    |
| catalog_url_product          | pending         | 0    |
| catalog_category_product_cat | pending         | 0    |
| targetrule                   | pending         | 0    |
+------------------------------+-----------------+------+
```

The `var/locks` directory seems to have active locks for every indexer, which doesn't make sense (surely the lock files should be removed when the index process has finished?:

```
$ ls -lah
total 64K
drwxrws--- 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Sep 23 22:56 .
drwxrws--- 8 www-data www-data 4.0K Sep 10 07:12 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_10.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_11.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_12.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_13.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_14.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 23 22:20 index_process_1.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 23 17:53 index_process_2.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_3.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_4.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_5.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_6.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_7.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_8.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Sep 24 00:10 index_process_9.lock
```

Any suggestions on how I can get some more visibility into the partial index process, what it's currently doing, and what progress it has made / what is yet to be indexed would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are also some other tables, check `enterprise_mview_*`.
Haven't worked for a while now with the enterprise indexers, but the last time I had configured XDebug for the console and analyzed what it does. Or just `Mage::log()` everywhere, but I do not recommend it over a real debugger.

Hope it get's you on the right track.